# не отображаются подсказки в vs code

Tags: c#

Я сам пытался ее решить долго, но не получается, помогите пж. У меня vs code не отображает подсказки кроме не которых(по типу: импортированных классов(например "using System"), самого кода(цикл for, while, try и тд)), я думаю это связано с всплывающим окном которое вылазит во время загрузки(в нем написано: установите .net, если он установлен перезапустите прогу и тд).

это картинка при запуске vs code

[image]

Comment: Установите .NET SDK, написано же

Comment: Похоже, что вы не установили .NET SDK. **Visual Studio Installer**(в поисковике) зайдите и скачайте.